# Shop By Brand/Manufacturer Dropdown

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

So I am trying to create a dropdown on my homepage that will allow the user to select a brand and it will bring them to a page with each product that has that attribute selected.

So I took a post (http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/magento-utility-function-how-to-easily-create-select-box-for-drop-down-attributes/) and made a few changes to how it is called since it was throwing a fatal error.

```
function getSelectBox($attributeCode, $label = '', $defaultSelect = null, $extraParams = null){
    $options            = array();
    $product            = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attribute          = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
    if($attribute->usesSource()){
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        array_unshift($options, array('label' => $label, 'value' => ''));
    }

    $select = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($attributeCode)
            ->setId($attributeCode)
            ->setTitle($label)
            ->setValue($defaultSelect)
            ->setExtraParams($extraParams)
            ->setOptions($options);
    return $select->getHtml();
}
```

This is the code that is calling the attributes inside of a dropdown.

The code I used to call it was:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('function')->getSelectBox('manufacturer', 'Select Manufacturer'); ?>
```

This worked and called all the manufacturers for me however the issue is that if I select one of the manufacturers in the dropdown it does not bring me to another page with the products.

Each product in my store is assigned a manufacturer. Each manufacturer is listed in the dropdown. I just want it so when I click on one of the manufacturer options that it will bring me to a list of those products that have said manufacturer assigned.

**I do not want an extension for this at all. Please refrain from suggesting them.**

I do realize I can create categories for each of the brands as well however I am unsure if that would be the smartest way to do this.

Thank you! I would really appreciate any help here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12872), using option #1, modified to work on Magento CE 1.9+:

```
<li>
 <a href="#">Browse by Manufacturer</a>
 <ul>
<?php $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
foreach ($options as $option)
{
    echo '<li style="list-style:none"><a href="'.Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result').'?manufacturer%5B%5D='.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</a></li>';
}
} ?>
 </ul>
</li>
```